# Can I add links to a JS array?

Tags: javascript

I want to have a link to add to each of the elements in the array below:

```
var breadcrumb = ['About','Test2','Test3','Test4' ];
```

I tried to add

```
<a href ="/about/">About</a>
```

etc and so on but not good.

Is there a way of doing this within the array? And how can I print them to my aspx page?

Thank you

Comment: When you assign it as an element it's just a string. I'm guessing you didn't wrap it in quotes. `var breadcrumb = ["<a href =\"/about/\">About</a>"]`

Comment: Oh, I did not, no. Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to store in the array? Is it the element tag with link? or the Strign of link only?

Comment: @msagala I wish to make a link above the page title which acts as the link and text "about" for the content 'on' page. Which is about. If that makes sense :-)

Comment: Use `createElement` to make a link, set the address, then add it to the array.

Comment: or maybe you can use Regexp, like django used in the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can put links or anything into a javascript array (use the real href values for you):

```
var breadcrumb = [
    "<a href='about.html'>About</a>",
    "<a href='test2.html'>Test2</a>",
    "<a href='test3.html'>Test3</a>",
    "<a href='test4.html'>Test4</a>"
];
```

If by printing you mean writing them to the page - I don't think this has anything specific to do with aspx since the array is in Javascript. You could do this:

```
for( var index = 0; index < breadcrumb.lengh; index++ ){
     document.write("<div>" + breadcrumb[index] + "</div>" );
}
```

Or you could use jQuery for more elaborate DOM manipulation to add your links to the page.